# Java Swing - JTree - setModel graphics bug on more then 2 chained branches

Tags: java, swing, model, jtree, invisible

I tried to create my own `JTree` Model so I can update the graphics by calling: `updateUI();`
I ran into a problem when my `JTree` should display a tree with a depth over 2 branches.

I use a own class that has extended by `java.util.Vector` called: `NamedVector`.

Here's how the tree should look like:

```
ROOT
    Branch
        BranchInside
              Leaf
              Leaf
              ...
        OtherBranch
     AndOneMore
        ...
     ...
```

And here's how it looks like: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/fehlerqq.png/

[image]

Here's how I set the new TreeModel:

```
jTree1.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.TreeModel(){

        @Override
        public Object getRoot(){
            return core.Project.sharedInstance.getTranslationsTree();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(Object parent, int index){
            if(parent instanceof String) return null;
            return ((core.NamedVector)parent).get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildCount(Object parent){
            if(parent instanceof String) return 0;
            return ((core.NamedVector)parent).size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Object node){
            if(node instanceof String) return true;
            return ((core.NamedVector)node).isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child){
            if(parent instanceof String) return -1;
            return ((core.NamedVector)parent).indexOf(child);
        }

        @Override
        public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue){}
        @Override
        public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l){}
        @Override
        public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l){}
    });
```

(`core.Project.sharedInstance.getTranslationsTree()` returns the root vector of my tree, when I print it in the console, it gives correct results.)

And here is my `NamedVector` class:

```
public class NamedVector extends java.util.Vector{
public String name;
public NamedVector(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
public static void dirToVector(java.io.File sourceLocation, NamedVector target){
    if(sourceLocation.isDirectory()){
        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for(int i=0; i<children.length; i++){
            NamedVector vector = new NamedVector(children[i]);
            target.add(vector);
            dirToVector(new java.io.File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    vector);
        }
    }
}
public void print(){
    print("");
}
private void print(String pre){
    System.out.println(pre+name);
    pre+=" ";
    for(int i=0;i<this.size();i++){
        if(get(i) instanceof NamedVector){
            ((NamedVector)get(i)).print(pre);
        }else{
            System.out.println(pre+get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}}
```

This only happens when I use my own model on the tree, if I build it with `DefaultMutableTreeNode` it displays everything correct, but I would like to use a custom model.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"i tried to create my own JTree Model"*  Why?  Is this homework?  If so, please mark it as such, if not, do the sensible thing and use a [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html).

Comment: If you're not dealing with your GUI's look and feel, there is no reason to call `udateUI` on a Swing component.

Comment: @Andrew But for DefaultTreeModel i have to add my nodes manually when i change my vector, i would like only changing my vector and calling the updateUI() method so my tree is builded by his own :(

Comment: noooo - do **not** call updateUI in application code. **never**. It's there for the exclusive use by the LAF. Whatever the application problem, the answer is **NOT** updatUI.

Comment: +1 for sweet mouse drawn red arrows courtesy of [Andrew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson).

Comment: @kleopatra how i let the `UIManager` invoke the `updateUI()` method?
what i did till now:
i used `DefaultTreeModel` and added my nodes as `DefaultMutableTreeNode`
my model is set to: askChildrenAllow=true
now my problem is that the tree wont display correct when i call the `repaint()` method on my `JTree`.
It only displays it correct when i call the `updateUI()` method.
(what he does: he only draws the root object, the node settings are correct).
Is there a way to update the tree instead of using `updateUI()`?

Comment: most probably your model implementation is invalid - it _must_ notify its listeners on change. Again: don't touch updateUI in application code, simply forget it exists.

Comment: @kleopatra thx i found a way to solve my problem, i asked my jTree for his model and reseted the root object after modifing the nodes of my root:
`((javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel)jTree1.getModel()).setRoot(root);`
what is updateUI? never heared of it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess, based on your comment

> But for DefaultTreeModel i have to add my nodes manually when i change my vector, i would like only changing my vector and calling the updateUI() method so my tree is builded by his own

is that your `TreeModel` does not fire the correct events. So when a change occurs in your vector, the `JTree` is not informed. Afterwards, when it repaints/expands a node/... and asks the `TreeModel` for information, this information will be out of sync with the info the `JTree` received through the events, typically resulting in `JTree`s as shown in your pictures.

Certainly if your model has empty implementations for the `addTreeModelListener` method

Comment: +1 See also the source of `DefaultTreeModel` for a basic implmentation of `TreeModel`.

Answer (score 2):

[`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) is an example that implements [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) for a typical hierarchical file system. There's an illustration in the [article](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui). It maybe useful to compare your implementation.